# What is the runtime complexity of this function considering that "in" is like a nested loop looking at lists as input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, runtime, big-o

python code:

```py
def disjoint(lst1,lst2):
    res = True
    for x in lst1:
       if x in lst2:
          res = False
    return res
```

So I thought this function has a runtime complexity of O(n^2) since "in" in Python also has a runtime complexity of O(n) with n = size of the list but my teacher somehow marked it as a mistake. Btw the function should return a boolean based on wether two lists are disjoint or not. (Dont mind that the function is inefficient it was given to us like that the follow up question was to implement a more efficient solution)

Comment: It will be O(n^2) only if `len(lst1) == len(lst2)`, otherwise it's O(n*m).

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume the sizes of lst1 and lst2 are n and m respectively
You have an outer loop that runs n times, and another one inside that runs m times. So you would get a time complexity of `O(n*m)`.
However if lst1 and lst2 are not lists, the time complexity of the `in`operator might be different.
For a set or dict the worst-case time complexity of `in` is O(n) and average-case of O(1), so for those you would get an average time complexity of O(n+m), if `n=m` then its average O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Given your case and code, you might be having unique elements in the lists. In that case, sets might be a better option.

```
def disjoint(lst1,lst2):
    lst1, lst2 = set(lst1), set(lst2)

    return len(lst1.intersection(lst2)) == 0

print(disjoint([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2]))
print(disjoint([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9]))
```

Output:

```
False
True
```

If the length of lists were `m` and `n` respectively, your code was taking `O(mn)` time, whereas the set intersection will take `O(n)` where n is the length of the smaller list.